# angular 2 4 5 - how to define object variable in component.ts

Tags: angular, angular5

I want to define object variable in component.ts

> components.ts

```
  user: {
         brand: {
                 id: string,
                name: string
         },
  [k: string]: any} = {};

  ==> I want Define 'brand' object to the 'user' variable
```

> view.html

```
  <form class="example-form">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input matInput [(ngModel)]="user.userName"> ==> *** No Error ***
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>

  <form class="example-form">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input matInput [(ngModel)]="user.brand.id"> ==> *** Error ***
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
```

> user.brand.id Error Message ==> Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Where the error is pointing  => user.brand.id

Comment: Was my solution helpful?

Answer (score 0):

This error message is showing because `user.brand` is undefined at the moment.
When I tried to mirror the problem, I didn't got any, because you are not sharing error inducing part of code. Most obvious cause of error might be initialization of your `user` model in component file or in its interface. Follow provided format to solve your problem
My code was ->

**Component File**

```
params: UserModel = {
  reg_username: '',
  password: {
     reg_password: ''
  }
};
foo(): void {
  this.params.password.reg_password = this.params.reg_username;
}
```

**Interface File**

```
export interface UserModel {
  reg_username: '';
  password: {
    reg_password: '';
  }
}
```

**HTML File**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="params.reg_username">
<p>Value: {{ params.reg_username }}</p>
<input [(ngModel)]="params.password.reg_password">
<p>Value: {{ params.password.reg_password }}</p>
<button (click)='foo()'>FOO</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.

I solved my problem in your code.
( I had already done that before you answered. )

I wanted to know. In type scripts ==> model initialization.

When initializing a model in a type script, how to define an object type.

```
params: UserModel = {
reg_username: '',
password: {
   reg_password: '' ==> '' I wondered if it was the right way in typescript
                        ex) normally reg_password: string; 
                               OR    reg_password: any;



}
```